# MongoDB replication to hard drive

Tags: mongodb, replication, production

MonogDB's dynamic schema design is driving me towards it to replace MySQL in a production site. But this project runs on only 1 dedicated server (with 2 hard drives).

Docs about "MongoDB for production" recommends multiple servers. This makes me wonder if MongoDB is only suited for large commercial projects?

Anyways... I am wondering if the live database data can be replicated to the second hard drive for backup & recovery (to recover from corrupt data due to hard stop).

Any thoughts against the use of MongoDB in a single server environment is also appreciated. In this project, the biggest database will be less than 7GB.

Thanks

Comment: Questions like this which are not about programming but about administration, maintainance and deployment of MongoDB, are much more suitable for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: In any production deployment with a single server / single point of failure you do not have the redundancy needed to survive most network partitions or other system failures. The advice for production is deploy to several machines. If you wanted to learn more about MongoDB before replacing an existing site then you could enable journaling and investigate replicasets on a single machine but this would not be a recommended production deployment.